# What's the suggested Esperanto word for "payload"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi uzis laborpezecon aux taskpezecon kaj mia korespondanto komprenas ilin, sed mi serĉas ĉu troviĝas pli bonaj aŭ pli belaj vortoj?

Comment: I've written an answer below, but taking another look at everything, I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. I don't understand *laborpezeco* and *taskpezeco* either. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluraj tradukaĵoj eblas, depende de la kunteksto. La vortumo "utila ŝarĝo" [ŝajnas](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22utila%20%C5%9Dar%C4%9Do%22) kutima ĉe transportado de varoj.

Alia ebla esprimo povus esti "utila kargo" (laŭ ReVo, *kargo* signifas "ŝarĝo de varoj en ŝipo, trajno, vagono, ajna transporta veturilo").

Comment: Dankon. Mi konsentas ambaux.

Answer (score 1):

Por la ĝenerala termino, "pagoŝarĝo" estas en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#pago%C5%9Dar%C4%9Do) kaj estas Zamenhofa.